# PHP Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't create a new thread (errno 11);

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following users registration script in a php web application:

```
function(x,y)
{
    //mysql insertion,updation
    if (user sponsor!=)//it might be 1000 or more iterations...
    {
        function(a,b)
    }
}
function (x,y);
```

like above I have one more script in same page. When I run script plenty of mysql records are inserted and updated. In localhost I increase memory limit because of taking lot of time. I did the same thing in my VPS.

Due to internal server error I upgraded from shared hosting to vps hosting.

Again here same thing happend I am getting internal server error amny times when I check server log it showing that:

> PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Can't create a new thread (errno 11); if you are not out of available memory, you can consult the manual for a possible OS-dependent bug in /home/xxx/xx/xxx/abc.php

I think this error is due to many mysql records updation. My client is very anger about me, can anyone explain this to me?

Please help me.

Comment: You will get a much better answer if you provide the actual function rather than an example of how it MIGHT be.

Comment: If you share the actual code I'm sure that someone will be able to identify where and how the problem is occurring and be able to suggest a remedy.

Comment: Improved text formatting

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self explanatory. It appears that you are running out of memory.
To find how much memory your MySQL server consumes, do the math:

> key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_connections = TOTAL Memory

Overall, it depends on how you configured your server in relation to memory and swap.

You might want to reduce the values above in line with the performance you require so you won't exceed the maximum amount of memory available. As you may know, your OS and other processes require memory too.